# pyspark conf and yarn top memory discrepancies

Tags: pyspark, memory-management, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

An EMR cluster reads (from main node, after running `yarn top`):

> ARN top - 13:27:57, up 0d, 1:34, 1 active users, queue(s): root
> NodeManager(s): 6 total, 6 active, 0 unhealthy, 2 decommissioned, 0
> lost, 0 rebooted Queue(s) Applications: 3 running, 8 submitted, 0
> pending, 5 completed, 0 killed, 0 failed Queue(s) Mem(GB): 18
> available, 189 allocated, 1555 pending, 0 reserved Queue(s) VCores: 44
> available, 20 allocated, 132 pending, 0 reserved Queue(s) Containers:
> 20 allocated, 132 pending, 0 reserved

```
                  APPLICATIONID USER             TYPE      QUEUE PRIOR   #CONT  #RCONT  VCORES RVCORES     MEM    RMEM  VCORESECS    MEMSECS %PROGR       TIME NAME
 application_1663674823778_0002 hadoop          spark    default     0      10       0      10       0     99G      0G      18754     187254  10.00   00:00:33 PyS
 application_1663674823778_0003 hadoop          spark    default     0       9       0       9       0     88G      0G       9446      84580  10.00   00:00:32 PyS
 application_1663674823778_0008 hadoop          spark    default     0       1       0       1       0      0G      0G        382        334  10.00   00:00:06 PyS
```

---

Note that the PySpark apps for `application_1663674823778_0002` and  `application_1663674823778_0003` were provisioned via the main node command line with just executing `pyspark` (with *no* explicit config editing).

However, the `application_1663674823778_0008` was provisioned via the following command: `pyspark --conf spark.executor.memory=11g --conf spark.driver.memory=12g`. Despite this (test) PySpark config customization, *that* app in yarn fails to show anything other than 0 for the memory (regular or reserved) value.

**Why is this?**

Comment: maybe because driver doesn't have enough 12g memory? what would happen if you run another `pyspark`? would it work?

Comment: great call out. I've since tested your suggestion and (just like the other apps listed from yarn output) another pyspark app is provisioned but with the same values as `application_1663674823778_0008`. maybe I'm not seeing this from the correct way in that (yarn) memory is read for just the driver, executor, or maybe both...I'm not sure

Comment: (1) are you saying yarn does not allocate any memory/core for the 3rd application started by `pyspark` command? (2) yarn does not do anything with driver

Comment: [1] = yes. 

[2] =  right. but, I'm saying that (assuming the `--conf` option successfully does what it's supposed to do) yarn does not seem to show the memory I've explicitly allocated for a given pyspark session application.